# Jenkins and Gitlab bundled with Redis and/or nginx?

Tags: jenkins, redis, gitlab

I'm establishing some monitoring on a few servers running jenkins and GitLab. My Monitoring agent auto discovers lots of metrics and identifies processes.

On all of my Jenkins and GitLab servers, I see nginx and Redis running as well. So my question is: Is GitLab or Jenkins bundled with any of the two?

I'd be suprised if these softwares are bundled. I access my jenkins via port 8080 so I didn't setup nginx as a proxy.

Thanks in advance for your help and Best Regards. Sebastian

Comment: if you have ssh access to your gitlab server, you can use gitlab-ctl status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [GitLab architecture documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/development/architecture.html), which lists all the components of the GitLab package, Redis and Nginx are both bundled with GitLab.

There is a full chart of components on that page that list which components come with which editions of GitLab, but Redis and Nginx look like they're fairly universal.

Jenkins does not bundle either Nginx or Redis.